# Telerik: RadComboBox How do delete all the items and add a new list

Tags: telerik, radcombobox

I am using a telerik radcombobox for a drop down list inside a user control in a web forms application. I need to delete all the items in the box, let's say id is ddlVeihicleMake and repopulate it with a new list of item passed to the function. Here is an example of what I understand it should be like,

```
function addNewItems(selectRef, optionsArray, valuesArray) {
    var combo = document.getElementById("ctl00_cpMain_ctl01_appRadPaneltabVehicleInformation_i0_i0_tabVehicleInformation_ddlVehicleMake_Input");
    combo.get_items().clear();
    for (var idx = 0; idx < optionsArray.length; idx++) {

        if (valuesArray == "") {
            var comboItem = new Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItem();
            comboItem.set_text(optionsArray[idx]);
            combo.trackChanges();
            combo.get_items().add(comboItem);
        } else {
            var comboItem = new Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItem();
            comboItem.set_text(optionsArray[idx]);
            combo.trackChanges();
            combo.get_items().add(comboItem);
        }

    }
```

It fails for me on get_items().clear() and get_itmes().add(comboItem). Appreciate any help I can get.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
function DeleteItems(sender, args)
{
    var combo = window.$find("<%= cboMyComboBox.ClientID %>");
    combo.trackChanges();
    for (var i = 0; i < combo.get_items().get_count(); i++) {
        combo.get_items().remove(combo.get_items().getItem(i));
    }
    combo.commitChanges();
}
```